# Android Studio - OpenCSV - Error java.io.FileNotFoundException: teste.csv: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, csv, filenotfoundexception, opencsv

I'm having some trouble working with OpenCSV in Android Studio. When I try to reference a file, it gives me the following error: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: teste.csv: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)".

Specs:
*Windows 10
*Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
**Project on Android Studio: "No activity"
*OpenCSV 5.7.1

MainActivity code **(UPDATED with codes InputStream, InputStreamReader, BufferedReader)**:

```
package com.example.testecsv;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.opencsv.CSVParserBuilder;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVReaderBuilder;
import com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvValidationException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        
        try {
            //#1 InputStreamReader code (no error)
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("teste.csv"));

            //#2 InputStream code (no error)
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("teste.csv");

            //#3 BufferedReader code (no error)
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("teste.csv"), "UTF-8"));

            // Code retrieved from OpenCSV site and documentation
            // New example from original post, got from OpenCSV documentation --> WHAT DO I PUT INSIDE "FileReader" ???
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new FileReader("teste.csv")).build();
            String [] nextLine;
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
                System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CsvValidationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The file exists on both "assets" folder and "res/raw" folder. Android Studio finds the FILE, but the compilation don't (on virtual or on physical device), here's some details of the error:

```
2022-12-18 15:39:15.232 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W  java.io.FileNotFoundException: teste.csv: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.280 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:574)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.281 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:160)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.283 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:115)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.284 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:60)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.285 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at com.example.testecsv.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.289 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8305)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.289 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8284)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.290 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1417)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.291 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3626)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.292 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.292 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.293 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.296 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.298 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.299 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.301 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.301 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.302 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.304 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.306 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.308 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.314 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W  Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.316 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.316 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:563)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.317 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:274)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.318 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:563)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.318 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7758)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.322 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:560)
2022-12-18 15:39:15.324 13198-13198 System.err              com.example.testecsv                 W      ... 20 more
```

I've tried a lot of codes, answers from internet (stackoverflow included), examples from documentation and outside documentation, but still struggling trying to simply READ a .csv file. It doesn't matter which code I write, it always can't find the file path, giving the error above (the code more above I wrote just to post it here like an example). I also tried using
"InputStream", "AssetManager", "FileInputStream" and a few others commands and codes. It still 4 days and it's stressing me out. I'm using my last resort which is asking here. I'm not an advanced programmer, I'm just trying to build a simple app to help some people. The answer might be something very simple, but I can't find it, and I'm feeling down, almost giving up to something so simple. Please be kind. Thanks for all who might help me.

**EDIT 1:**

With the following added code, I can read the .csv file by the normal way, but I'm still struggling how I can link this code with the OpenCSV Code.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("teste.csv"), "UTF-8"));
ArrayList lines = new ArrayList<String>();
String newLine;
    while ((newLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(newLine);
        lines.add(newLine);
    }
br.close();
```

Comment: FileReader will not read files residing in assets or res\raw.

Comment: `I also tried using "InputStream", "AssetManager",` Yes!!! That is what you need to use if the file is in assets. Let us see you tried to use them! Show how you opened an input stream for a file in assets.

Comment: `new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("teste.csv"))` should work, if your `assets/` directory is the correct spot and `teste.csv` is directly in that directory. FWIW, [this source code](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/blob/master/DiceLight/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/diceware/PassphraseRepository.java) is profiled in [this section](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-arch-003) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack).

Comment: @blackapps I've tried the following, got same error: `FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("teste.csv"); InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);` and `FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("teste.csv");
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(file);`, **BUT** `InputStream is = getAssets().open("teste.csv");` doesn't give the error, is it the correct way? How do I link with CSVReader?

Comment: @CommonsWare, look at following image, is it correct? The Android Studio finds the file [link](https://ibb.co/q7vjY8q) I'm still working on the code you gave.

Comment: @Azzullino: In terms of where your `assets/` directory goes, yes, that looks fine. It should be at the same level as `res` and `java`.

Comment: Please post your code in your post. Not unreadable in comments.

Comment: Sorry @blackapps. I just updated with the new code. The 3 alternatives commands I've tested (InputStream, InputStreamReader, BufferedReader) doesn't outputs the ENOENT Error, so I think they found the .csv file. I just need to know how I bind them with the OpenCSV code to read the .csv file.

Comment: Yesterday i googled for CSVReader reader = new CSVReaderBuilder and immedialy found such a piece of code.